# How to combine subset of rows from multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am looking at binding rows in R with its subset of column names.

**Code**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
df2 <- data.frame(subset_a = c(11:15), subset_b = c(16:20), f = LETTERS[1:5])
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
result
```

The code above produces the results below, however, I am looking for the results with the merged rows specified in the expected output.

**Current results**

```
a   b   subset_a    subset_b    c
1   6   NA             NA      <NA>
2   7   NA             NA      <NA>
3   8   NA             NA      <NA>
4   9   NA             NA      <NA>
5   10  NA             NA      <NA>
NA  NA  11             16       A
NA  NA  12             17       B
NA  NA  13             18       C
NA  NA  14             19       D
NA  NA  15             20       E
```

**Expected results**

```
a   b   c
1   6   NA
2   7   NA
3   8   NA
4   9   NA
5   10  NA
11  16  A
12  17  B
13  18  C
14  19  D
15  20  E
```

I believe it should be possible to do so using regular expressions in column names, but I'm not sure how.

Could someone please assist me in resolving this?

Comment: Hi Kevin, i see how you are arriving at the results for columns a and b in the expected results, but I don't understand the rationale for column c. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Joe Erinjeri, Apologize, I edited my post in 'Expected results'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work

```r
library(dplyr)

expected_results<-result %>%
  mutate(a_new=if_else(is.na(a),subset_a,a)) %>%
  mutate(b_new=if_else(is.na(b),subset_b,b)) %>%
  select(a_new, b_new,f) %>%
  rename(a=a_new, b=b_new,c=f)

expected_results
#>     a  b    c
#> 1   1  6 <NA>
#> 2   2  7 <NA>
#> 3   3  8 <NA>
#> 4   4  9 <NA>
#> 5   5 10 <NA>
#> 6  11 16    A
#> 7  12 17    B
#> 8  13 18    C
#> 9  14 19    D
#> 10 15 20    E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Please find below a maybe more direct way of getting what you are looking for through the `coalesce()` and `summarise()` functions of the `dplyr` library:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

result %>% 
  summarise(a = coalesce(a, subset_a),
            b = coalesce(b, subset_b),
            c = f)
```

- Output

```r
#>     a  b    c
#> 1   1  6 <NA>
#> 2   2  7 <NA>
#> 3   3  8 <NA>
#> 4   4  9 <NA>
#> 5   5 10 <NA>
#> 6  11 16    A
#> 7  12 17    B
#> 8  13 18    C
#> 9  14 19    D
#> 10 15 20    E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**EDIT following the OP's comment**

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

result %>% 
  summarise(a = coalesce(!!!select(., ends_with("a"))),
            b = coalesce(!!!select(., ends_with("b"))),
            c = f)
```

- Output

```r
#>     a  b    c
#> 1   1  6 <NA>
#> 2   2  7 <NA>
#> 3   3  8 <NA>
#> 4   4  9 <NA>
#> 5   5 10 <NA>
#> 6  11 16    A
#> 7  12 17    B
#> 8  13 18    C
#> 9  14 19    D
#> 10 15 20    E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How to acquire the required results by using a regular expression for column names (for example, it always ends with an or b in names).

Comment: Hi @Kevin Tracey, please find above the edit to answer your comment. Cheers.